# Something wrong with Marquee progress bar

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, progress-bar, marquee

I'm learning to use thread and make some multi-threading demo.
I have a label named **lblText** and a marquee progress bar named **pgbRun**. I make 2 threads, one let label's text change after each `Thread.Sleep()` called, other let progress bar show animation when label's text is changing.
The problem I have is the text-changing thread seem to work well, but progress bar thread have something wrong. The **pgbRun** just start animating after text-changing done. 
Please help me find what wrong with my code, and show me some way to fix it. Thanks so much!

```
private delegate void formDelegate();

private void btnRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(new formDelegate(textChange)));
    thread.IsBackground = true;
    thread.Start();
}

public void textChange()
{
    if (lblText.InvokeRequired)
    {
        lblText.BeginInvoke(new formDelegate(textChange));
    }
    else
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(new formDelegate(progess))); 
        thread.IsBackground = true;
        thread.Start();

        //I try make single thread that config progress bar here but i have same trouble.

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            lblText.Text = "Count: " + i;
            lblText.Update();
            lblText.Refresh();
            Thread.Sleep(300);
        }
    }
}

public void progess()
{
    if (pgbRun.InvokeRequired)
    {
        pgbRun.BeginInvoke(new formDelegate(progess));
    }
    else
    {
        pgbRun.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
        pgbRun.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 20;
        pgbRun.Update();
        pgbRun.Refresh();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your threads don't do anything useful, they immediately invoke to the UI thread.  The textChange() code doesn't accomplish much more but cause the UI to hang for 3 seconds.  You can see the label change because you call Update().  The BeginInvoke() call in the progess() is stuck for those 3 seconds since the UI thread is busy sleeping so you don't see anything happening with the progressbar.  You'll need to throw this code away.

Comment: @HansPassant so how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I read [this very useful article](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/winforms.shtml), I see #Hans is so true. My first code is trash, so I edit my code as below. Basic properties of progress bar is set in designer, in code I just change visible option.

```
delegate void textChangeDelegate(int x);

private void btnRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(new MethodInvoker(threadJob)));
    thread.IsBackground = true;
    thread.Start();
}

public void threadJob()
{
    Invoke(new MethodInvoker(show));
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Invoke(new textChangeDelegate(textChange),new object[]{i});
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
    Invoke(new MethodInvoker(hide));
}

public void textChange(int x)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        BeginInvoke(new textChangeDelegate(textChange),new object[] {x});
        return;
    }
    x += 1;
    lblText.Text = "Count: " + x;
}

public void show()
{
    pgbRun.Visible = true;
    lblText.Visible = true;
}

public void hide()
{
    pgbRun.Visible = false;
    lblText.Text = "";
    lblText.Visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should using Microsoft's Reactive Framework for this. It'll make it so much easier.

Here's the code:

```
private void btnRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Observable
        .Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300.0))
        .Take(10)
        .Select(n => String.Format("Count: {0}", n))
        .ObserveOn(this)
        .Subscribe(t => lbl.Text = t);
}
```

That's it.

Just NuGet "Rx-WinForms" and add that to your project.

It wasn't clear what you're trying to do with the progress bar. Can you please provide more detail on that?

Comment: Thank for your answer. I'm try to create a multi-thread demo with two thread. One change the label's text, and other "turn on" progressbar while those text is charging. I really appreciate you with that nice framework, but I need to work around with threading and multi-thread. So your solution should useful for me in the future.

Comment: @tungns304 - This is multi-threading. It just uses a framework that manages the threads for you. Everything prior to the `ObserveOn(this)` happens on a background thread, and then afterwards back on the UI thread.